# CLOSED octave - variable change propagation

Tags: octave

In Octave 4.0.3, I can't think of a way to propagate variable changes:

```
> foo=5;
> f=foo
f =  5
> foo=3;
> f
f =  5
```

Same goes for anonymous functions:

```
> foo=5;
> f=@(x) x+foo;
> f(0)
ans =  5
> foo=3;
> f(0)
ans =  5              % f closes over the workspace
> f=@(x) x+foo;       % Reassign, causing a lookup of the value of foo
> f(0)
ans =  3
```

Any way to propagate variable changes across the workspace (like Geogebra)?

Comment: No. `=` denotes assignment of a value to a variable, not equivalence of two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get 'propagation' behaviour within named functions with global variables if you wish, e.g.

```
global foo;
function [a] = f(x) global foo; a = x+foo; end
```

Then

```
>> foo = 5
>> f(0)
ans =  5
>> foo = 3;
>> f(0)
ans =  3
```

see `help global`.

Otherwise, see the comment above. `=` is an assignment of value operator, it does not work 'by reference'.

Another option is to use `evalin()` to fetch a variable from a different scope. See `help evalin`. The following function will produce the same output as the above example

```
function [a] = f(x) a = x+evalin('base','foo'); end
```

A final note - variables can be propagated within a function via nested functions. See if you can guess the output of

```
function [] = f(x)
    function [c] = g(y)
        c = y + x;
    end
    disp(g(x));
    x=x+1;
    disp(g(x));
end
f(0)
```

Comment: `evalin` is another option, and variable propagation can occur within a function. Just FYI.